# Java security policy is not enforced

Tags: java, security, policy

I am working an example from Learning Java that discusses creating a security policy to allow socket connection.  I have added a policy file that allows the application to open the connection. But when I run it, the connection is not allowed.

Any help is greatly appeciated.

Tom

```
Here is the code

        //file: EvilEmpire.java
import java.net.*;

public class EvilEmpire {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    try {
      Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.1", 80);
      System.out.println("Connected!");
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
      System.out.println("SecurityException: could not connect.");
    }
  }
}

And here is the policy file


grant codeBase "file:/c:/users/flash/eclipse-workspace/learning java/bin/" {
  permission java.net.SocketPermission "192.168.0.1", "connect";
};
```

Comment: What is actual error? Maybe you got `connection refused` which is not related to security manager, but rather by fact that endpoint you are trying to connect is not running.

Comment: By default regular Java applications already have the permission to open/connect to any socket on the network. In which context do you execute your program that you think you need additional permissions?

Comment: It says "SecurityException: could not connect." from the catch clause

Comment: I'm running it from the Eclipse IDE

Answer (score -1):

Well, just did an update on eclipse and now the program runs properly.  I don't know if it was the update or the fact that the IDE was restarted.

Thanks everyone for your comments.

Tom